# Video is lagging from Audio in a vLine media session

Tags: html, audio, video, webrtc, vline

At first I have a voice call in a vLine session, I hear the audio by getting the audio tag calling `createAudioElement()` on the media stream and appending it to the `$(body)`

Then on when the remote user opens his video, I send this piece of info to the other user using an `x-msg`, after received I get the video stream by calling `createVideoElement()` on the media stream.

After that I find a lag between the audio and the video, the audio always reaching faster than the video, how can I synchronize the audio with the video in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `createVideoElement` on the stream it will create a `<video>` element, which plays both audio and video, so at that point there is no need for the `<audio>` element that you created with `createAudioElement`.

The browser handles synchronizing the audio and video in a single `MediaStream`, so if they are consistently out of sync, you may need to file a [WebRTC bug](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/list).